# Problema ao tentar inserir alerta de maioridade em loja online

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web

```
<body>
<script>
function menor_idade(){
location.href="https://criancas.uol.com.br/"
}
function maior_idade(){
document.cookie="aceita_conteudo_pagina:sim";
window.location = location.href;
}
if(document.cookie.indexOf("aceita_conteudo_pagina")<0){
var home_principal = $$(".cms-index-index")
home_principal[0].innerHTML+="<h1 style="font-size: 32px; margin: 30px auto; text-align: center;">Este site oferece conteúdo impróprio para menos de 18 anos</h1>";
home_principal[0].innerHTML="<div id="master" style="height: 40px; text-align: center;"><span style="padding: 5px; background: green; color: #FFF; font-size: 18px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="maior_idade()">Tenho mais de 18 anos</span><span style="margin-left: 40px; padding: 5px; background: red; color: #FFF; font-size: 18px; cursor: pointer;"onclick="menor_idade()">Tenho menos de 18 anos</span></div>"
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Dica: Adicionar múltiplas *tags* só por adicionar, não vai ajuda-lo e provavelmente outros membros podem pedir o fechamento da pergunta.

Comment: Sobre o erro, remova um cifrão `$$` correto seria `$`; O segundo `innerHTML` está faltando o sinal de `+`, dessa forma ele está apenas reescrevendo o código interno do elemento; É necessário "escapar" as aspas de seu código (de ambos `innerHTML`), por exemplo `"<div id=\"master\" …"`

Answer (score 1):

Como o @ValdeirPsr falou...

Na linha

```
var home_principal = $$(".cms-index-index")
```

Retire um dos `$`, ficaria assim:

```
var home_principal = $(".cms-index-index")
```

No `innerHTML` te 2 problemas:

1- Em

```
home_principal[0].innerHTML+="<h1 style="font-size: 32px; margin: 30px auto; text-align: center;">Este site oferece conteúdo impróprio para menos de 18 anos</h1>";
home_principal[0].innerHTML="<div id="master" style="height: 40px; text-align: center;"><span style="padding: 5px; background: green; color: #FFF; font-size: 18px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="maior_idade()">Tenho mais de 18 anos</span><span style="margin-left: 40px; padding: 5px; background: red; color: #FFF; font-size: 18px; cursor: pointer;"onclick="menor_idade()">Tenho menos de 18 anos</span></div>"
```

Na segunda linha você está sobre escrevendo o `innerHTML` da primeira linha

```
home_principal[0].innerHTML+="<h1 style="font-size: 32px; margin: 30px auto; text-align: center;">Este site oferece conteúdo impróprio para menos de 18 anos</h1>";
home_principal[0].innerHTML="<div id="master" style="height: 40px; text-align: center;"><span style="padding: 5px; background: green; color: #FFF; font-size: 18px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="maior_idade()">Tenho mais de 18 anos</span><span style="margin-left: 40px; padding: 5px; background: red; color: #FFF; font-size: 18px; cursor: pointer;"onclick="menor_idade()">Tenho menos de 18 anos</span></div>"
```

2- Quando você quer usar aspas dentro de outras aspas precisa "escapar" as aspas internas com `\` ou mudar as aspas duplas por aspas simples,
ou seja, por fora use " e dentro ' ou vice-versa.

Com os dois erros do `innerHTML` corrigidos ficaria assim:

```
home_principal[0].innerHTML+="<h1 style='font-size: 32px; margin: 30px auto; text-align: center;'>Este site oferece conteúdo impróprio para menos de 18 anos</h1>";
home_principal[0].innerHTML+="<div id='master' style='height: 40px; text-align: center;'><span style='padding: 5px; background: green; color: #FFF; font-size: 18px; cursor: pointer;' onclick='maior_idade()'>Tenho mais de 18 anos</span><span style='margin-left: 40px; padding: 5px; background: red; color: #FFF; font-size: 18px; cursor: pointer;' onclick='menor_idade()'>Tenho menos de 18 anos</span></div>"
```

Aspas duplas para marcar início e fim da string e aspas simples para marcar início e fim dos atributos das tags HTML